# Solve $\cos\theta-3\cos2\theta+\cos3\theta=\sin\theta-3\sin2\theta+\sin3\theta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

My attempt:
\begin{align*}
\cos\theta-3\cos2\theta+\cos3\theta&=\sin\theta-3\sin2\theta+\sin3\theta\\
\cos\theta-3\cos2\theta+4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta&=\sin\theta-3\sin2\theta+3\sin\theta-4\sin^3\theta\\
-2\cos\theta-3\cos2\theta+4\cos^3\theta&=4\sin\theta-3\sin2\theta-4\sin^3\theta
\end{align*}
I have faced several symmetric trigonometry problems most of them need to use product to sum identities, but this one I can't continue.

Comment: hint: factor formulae https://www.examsolutions.net/tutorials/proving-identities-using-factor-formulae/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $\cos\theta+\cos3\theta = 2\cos\theta\cos2\theta$
> $\sin\theta+\sin3\theta = 2\sin2\theta\cos\theta$

So,

$\cos2\theta( 2\cos\theta-3) = \sin2\theta(2\cos\theta -3)$

Answer (score 3):

It's $$2\cos2\theta\cos\theta-3\cos2\theta=2\sin2\theta\cos\theta-3\sin2\theta$$ or
$$(2\cos\theta-3)(\cos2\theta-\sin2\theta)=0$$ or
$$\tan2\theta=1.$$
Can you end it now?

Answer (score -1):

It is a false identity. [Click here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rvxe1ip7qu) to see the graphs.

Comment: I don't think the OP is stating it as an identity, but instead an equation to be solved for $\theta$.

Comment: Corry, I didn't see it. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: Corry?  Who is Corry?